# What are some unanswered questions or unexplored areas in financial mathematics?

Tags: general

EDIT: Specifically Ito/Stochastic calculus or alternatives to the Wiener process framework itself.

Context: This might or might not matter, but I am currently pursuing my MSc in Financial Mathematics.

Comment: Flagged as too broad. Based on the question style, I doubt that you are familiar with the answered questions and explored areas. This would be your first step on your journey to the unanswered topics.